# Trouble selecting drop-down menu selector using AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, ajax

Currently I'm trying to create a page where my database is updated upon a drop event. More specifically, I have a page with drag-drop capabilities, what I need is anytime I drag and drop a particular div (deal-card) into a another div (stage-column), I need to make update to the database, that represents that "deal" placed in a different "stage".

For this project my backend is Django, and up to this point, I'm able to successfully change the basic CharFields on a drop event, though selecting a selector in the drop-down menu has me stumped.

As of now I just arbitrarily picked "value" = 3 for the targeted selector, just to see if I could get it to work. Unfortunately, whatever I try, I always get a prompt saying "This field is required". I attached a picture showing this below.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**AJAX CODE**

```
$(document).one('drop', function(ev){
            ev.preventDefault();

            var stage_title_path = '#' + el.id + " .stage-title";
            var stage_title = $(stage_title_path).html();
            
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:deal_card_url,
                data:{
                    deal_owner: 'Sally Sue',
                    deal_address: '745 Amen Street',
                    deal_arv: '222',
                    deal_repair: '333',
                    
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
                },
                success:function(){
                    $("#id_stage").val("3").change();
                }
            });

        });
```

**FORM DROP-DOWN HTML**

```
<p><label for="id_stage">Stage:</label> <select name="stage" required="" id="id_stage">
  <option value="">---------</option>

  <option value="1" selected="">New</option>

  <option value="2">Sent Offer</option>

  <option value="3">Under Contract</option>

  <option value="4">Option</option>

  <option value="5">Closed</option>

  <option value="24">New Lead</option>

</select></p>
```

[Ajax Updated Deal Update Webpage:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNu3E.png)

Comment: this line should be "on" instead of "one" `$(document).one(' `, that said, the "field required " message is not related to the Ajax. To test if the Ajax is triggered, you can use a `console.log('ajax triggered'); ` or similar messsage.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Alex. The reason I'm using "one" instead of "on", is because with "on" it was pulling up previous drop events along with the most recent one. Using "one" made it so no previous drop events were considered. As for the "field required", I'm aware it doesn't say explicitly whether Ajax was triggered. The ajax clearly ran, as the charfields changed. I pointed the field required out just to show my code for selecting a selector isn't working, while everything else is. Hope that clarifies my question a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It was actually quite simple...

For the "data" setting in the ajax function I needed to specify the "value" of the desired selector (aka stage), as shown in the code below.

```
data:{
     deal_owner: 'Sally Sue',
     deal_address: '745 Amen Street',
     deal_arv: '222',
     deal_repair: '333',
     stage: "2",
```

In this case passing a stage "value" equal to "2", as seen in the html, corresponds to the "Sent Offer" option in the drop-down menu. Previously I tried to use the actual name of the selector (eg. Sent Offer).